# VB.NET error while executing Postgresql stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am getting error while executing Postgresql(version 11) from VB.Net(2019)

I am executing a stored procedure from VB.NET 2019 on Postgresql 11. The error details are below.

Npgsql.PostgresException: '42809: spx_temp_to_ext() is a procedure'

The stored procedure is working correctly on Postgresql server and doesn't have any input parameters

```
Dim SQLCONN As New Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection
Dim SQLCMD As New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand
SQLCONN.ConnectionString = 
"SERVER=localhost;PORT=5432;DATABASE=xxxx;Uid=postgres;Password=xxxx"
SQLCMD.Connection = SQLCONN
SQLCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
SQLCMD.CommandText = "spx_temp_to_ext"
SQLCONN.Open()
SQLCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLCONN.Close()
```

Getting error '42809: spx_temp_to_ext() is a procedure', although command type is defined as a stored procedure

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. By using commandtype as stored procedure, a select statement is automatically generated in VB.Net. To maintain backward compatibility, Postgresql stored procedures can't be called using select statements, we need to use Call method for that.

So it will be

```
command.text = "Call Stored_Procedure_Name()"
```